# GetPrivateProfileString inconsistent behaviour when compiled with different Visual Studio versions

Tags: winapi

We have a c++ program compiled long ago that uses [GetPrivateProfileString](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms724353(v=vs.85).aspx). The `lpFileName` arg is just the name of an ini file, so the expected behaviour according to the documentation is that it should look for the file in the Windows directory:

> lpFileName [in] 
>   The name of the initialization file. If this parameter
>   does not contain a full path to the file, the system searches for the
>   file in the Windows directory.

Recently the program was recompiled (with no code changes) and redeployed, which resulted in the program not being able to read the ini file anymore.

Comparisons between the two programs with Process Monitor showed that the old program was attempting to look for the file in %HOMEPATH%\Windows rather than C:\Windows.

As a test I compiled the following code with Visual Studio 2012 and ran it on a 2003 server, passing in some random file name on the command line:

```
void wmain(int argc, wchar_t* argv[])
{
    wchar_t *appName = L"xxx";
    wchar_t *keyName = L"yyy";
    wchar_t *defValue = L"default value";
    wchar_t buffer[1024];
    DWORD bufferSize = sizeof(buffer);
    wchar_t *fileName = argv[1];

    DWORD result = GetPrivateProfileString(
        appName,
        keyName,
        defValue,
        buffer,
        bufferSize,
        fileName
        );

    wprintf(L"result: %d\n", result);
}
```

Using Process Monitor to monitor for that file name, I could see it looked for the file in C:\Windows - as expected. However when the exact same code is compiled in VS 2003 and run on 2003 server, it looks for the file in %HOMEPATH%\Windows.

Back to the original, non-recompiled program. I noticed that on a Windows 2008 server, if I simply double click the exe, it looks for the file in %HOMEPATH%\Windows. However if I right-click the exe and Run As Administrator, it looks for the file in C:\Windows! But on Windows Server 2003 it always looks in %HOMEPATH%\Windows.

This isn't consistent with the documentation!

Comment: Yeah, this long deprecated function is full of weird compat shims and undocumented oddness. Add then you are deciding to put the ini file in the system's Windows directory. Really?!!. It's 2016. Time to stop using this API, and time to stop polluting the system directory.  Well, it was time to do all of that over 20 years ago. Get a native C or C++ ini file parser and remove yourself from the tyranny of this API.

Comment: If you are going to keep using this obsolete API, at a bare minimum, **specify a full path**. Don't store your crap in the Windows directory. This was broken even before you noticed it.

Comment: @CodyGray Indeed, I forgot to mention that the incorrect behaviour was the behaviour being relied upon - for whatever reason we store the ini file in %HOMEPATH%\Windows. Now that it works correctly, it broke the program! This post is more about the "why" of this behaviour rather than how to fix it.

Comment: My guess is that it is related to virtualization and UAC. If you try to write to Windows directory that will fail with UAC. But if your process is virtualized, then that will redirect to the virtual store one would expect. If the file exists in virtual store, it will be read from there, if the process is virtualized.  All of this is guesswork though. It's pointless to worry about it. You need to fix your badly broken program.

Comment: @david UAC was my first thought, but that can't be. Server 2003 doesn't have UAC, but it's still doing the virtualization. It's probably related to Terminal Server awareness. Eurotrash seems insistent upon an explanation of this behavior, so I composed an answer that he can accept so he can get busy fixing his program.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The behavior is almost certainly related to Terminal Server. When you have Terminal Server (later renamed to Remote Desktop Services in Server 2003 and later SKUs) installed, any attempts to access the system (Windows) directory get redirected to a user-local Windows directory (`%HOMEPATH%\Windows`).

This is documented under the "remarks" section of the documentation for [GetWindowsDirectory()](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms724454.aspx), which is presumably what GetPrivateProfileString() is using under the hood when you don't specify a full path and it falls back to its 16-bit Windows behavior of looking in the system directory.

If you are linking your binary with the `IMAGE_DLLCHARACTERISTICS_TERMINAL_SERVER_AWARE` flag (set in the Project Property Pages under Linker → System → Terminal Server → [`/TSAWARE:YES`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/01cfys9z(v=vs.110).aspx)), then it assumes you are aware of this behavior and understand that Terminal Servers are different than normal client machines. Thus, it gives you the actual Windows directory, instead of the private Windows directory.

Otherwise, if you're linking with `/TSAWARE:NO`, then you get the backwards-compatibility behavior that redirects requests for the system Windows directory to the private user-local Windows directory.

Presumably the default setting of this flag changed some time between VS 2003 and VS 2012. I don't know when exactly, but modern versions of Visual Studio do assume you are Terminal Server-aware.

Raymond Chen blogged about this once: [When will GetSystemWindowsDirectory return something different from GetWindowsDirectory?](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20140723-00/?p=423/)

---

Anyway, this is all just academic curiosity. Your program is buggy, and it was long before you discovered this curiosity. An application should never write data into the Windows directory, whether the system Windows directory or a pseudo-user-local Windows directory. There are two ways of getting around this:

1. Stop calling GetPrivateProfileString() altogether and, as David Heffernan suggested, use a third-party INI-file parser. Google will turn up several results. [simpleini](https://github.com/brofield/simpleini) looks like a good choice.
2. If you aren't ready to make the change yet, you should *at a minimum* be specifying a full path to your INI file. That will avoid the 16-bit Windows behavior of dumping files in the system directory, but you're still at the mercy of the other crustiness of this ancient API.

Comment: It was in fact the TSAWARE switch.